# Power BI how using measure to rank for years columns

Tags: powerbi, ranking, rank, measure

I using direct query and unable to create column, it there any way can using measure to create ranking for year column? eg: 2016 rank as 1; 2017 rank as 2; 2018 rank as 3; 2019 rank as 4;......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax for rankx in DAX

rankImpressions = 
RANKX(
    ALL('Weekly Summary'),
    CALCULATE ( SUM('Weekly Summary'[Impressions]) ),
    ,
    ASC
)

Link:  https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/RANKX-returning-all-ranks-as-1/td-p/143116